# Error to SetDataSource for ReportDocument in Visual studio 2010 (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Operation system: Windows7 64bit

Visual studio 2010 (C#):
Properties of in Solution Explorer:
Target framework: .NET Framework 4

My Code:

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();//Line1
rd.FileName = "rpt1.rpt";//Line2
rd.SetDataSource(getinfo());//Line3
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;//Line4
crystalReportViewer1.Show();//Line5
```

Error in line 3:
Error load file (file is exists):
Picture of error:
http://s2.picofile.com/file/7873257090/SetDataSource.png

Comment: Please change the host of your image: picofile.com doesn't support https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open app.config and add code:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
<runtime>
  <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
</runtime>
```